# mine filter remove in woocommerce order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

I installed the plugin "WooCommerce Order Status Manager". When we change any custom status order, the status changes successfully but this order also show in the "MINE" filter list.

[image]

How can I remove this mine filter?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Very few people are going to click a link that goes to prntscr.com. It would be preferable to use the image hosting that is linked through the editor. Please read Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

add to this in theme funtion.php file

```js
function jp_filter_edit_shop_order_views( $views ) { 
    // Unset the Mine option. 
    unset( $views['mine'] );
    return $views; 
}; 
add_filter( 'views_edit-shop_order', 'jp_filter_edit_shop_order_views' );
```